# Filtering database values based on date

Tags: iphone, ios, filter, nsdate

I need to pull my 'expenses' values from Database based on the date like last 10, last 30 days, last 60 days, etc.  Note: Each expense field has a date field in the format m/dd/yyyy. Can anyone help me on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
NSDateComponents *comps = [NSDateComponents new];
comps.days = -10; // Change this as per your need
NSDate *pastDate = [calendar dateByAddingComponents:comps toDate:[NSDate date] options:0]; //This will give you past date
```

Comment: what is new here other than my answer below ?

Comment: @Manoj Ellappan, what is the new change you have found with this answer that you have un-accepted my answer and accepted this one ?

Answer (score 1):

try like this,

```
[NSString stringWithFormat:@"SELECT  *FROM tablename WHERE  dLastLotteryDate <= '%@'",passDateHere]
```

EDIT:-

check like this it'l helps you i think,

```
> SELECT * FROM tablename WHERE dateField >= date('now','-10 day')
> SELECT * FROM tablename WHERE dateField >= date('now','-30 day')
> SELECT * FROM tablename WHERE dateField >= date('now','-60 day')
```

Comment: pass date whatever you want calculate date before 30days and pass that value here.

Comment: @ManojEllappan I have posted answer for "how to find the last XX days date" above. Check it.

Answer (score 1):

Use this query :

```
select * from your_tablename where date_column_name <= your_date
```

Answer (score 1):

I assume you have stored your date in database.

Now to get date like last 10, last 30 days, last 60 days try this way,

```
NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
NSDateComponents *comps = [NSDateComponents new];
comps.days = -10; // Change this as per your need
NSDate *pastDate = [calendar dateByAddingComponents:comps toDate:[NSDate date] options:0]; //This will give you past date
```

Then apply this date to your query as Sunny suggested here.